# Javascript; pushing common elements from 2 lists to a new list

Tags: javascript, list

```
let listOne = [Bill, Joe, Trever, Neil, Jim, Pam, Michael]
let listTwo = [Petter, Pam, Steven, Jim, Michael, Scott]
```

I have two lists but I want to create a new list with only the names in both lists.

```
[Jim, Pam, Michael]
```

**What I did:**

I create a nested loop to push each name into a new list

**what I need help with:**

I feel there is a better way to do this. without having to nest my loops. Perhaps somehow filtering through both lists simultaneously somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
let listOne = [Bill, Joe, Trever, Neil, Jim, Pam, Michael]
let listTwo = [Petter, Pam, Steven, Jim, Michael, Scott]

let result = listOne.filter(item => listTwo.includes(item))
```

Comment: Hello Vitor!! I am writing to you to ask for some help in this other issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70657714/ngx-translate-when-deployed-does-not-load-json-files

Comment: Hello Vitor!, I would like to share to you this question also:     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70761156/change-url-when-using-ngx-translate

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) here. Checking the existence of `name` in `Set` is efficient, if you gonna use [`has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) method of `set`.

```js
let listOne = ["Bill", "Joe", "Trever", "Neil", "Jim", "Pam", "Michael"];
let listTwo = ["Petter", "Pam", "Steven", "Jim", "Michael", "Scott"];

const set = new Set(listOne);
const result = listTwo.filter(name => set.has(name));
// or
// const result = listTwo.filter(set.has.bind(set));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use Array.prototype.reduce, have the callback search the other list, and only insert the name if it is in the other list.

```js
listOne.reduce((prev, cur)=>{
    if(listTwo.includes(cur)){
        prev.push(cur);
    }
    return prev;
});
```

EDIT: After further testing, Array.prototype.reduce requires the first and second arguments to have a type of number, so I would recommend using filter instead. (see other answers)
However, if you want to use reduce, you would have to use something like this:

```js
let listOne = ["Bill", "Joe", "Trever", "Neil", "Jim", "Pam", "Michael"];
let listTwo = ["Petter", "Pam", "Steven", "Jim", "Michael", "Scott"];
let results = [];
listOne.reduce((prev, cur)=> {
  if(listTwo.includes(cur)){
    results.push(cur);
  }
  return;
});
console.log(results); // Prints [ 'Jim', 'Pam', 'Michael' ]
```

My recommendation is to use the accepted answer by Vitor Franca and use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter)

Comment: You haven't specified the second argument to reduce. so how could you use `prev.push(cur);`. Dude, this is not the right solution

Answer (score -1):

```js
const listOne = ["Bill", "Joe", "Trever", "Neil", "Jim", "Pam", "Michael"]
const listTwo = ["Petter", "Pam", "Steven", "Jim", "Michael", "Scott"]

const newList = listOne.filter(item => listTwo.indexOf(item) > -1)
console.log(newList)
```